# Unable to install Anaconda for second time

Tags: anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1GRd.jpg)Screen shot of installing page beginning

[image: screen shot of installing page beginning]

I was using Anaconda in my laptop. I have uninstalled and tried to install again . While installing I have selected "Add Anaconda to my PATH Env variable" due to this installation never ends. it stops at preparing cache page...

Comment: check in environment variables that anaconda path is already available or not.  If it was there,  then remove from environment variables.  And check is there any anaconda belongigs folder of previous version. If it was there backup the necessary files, and delete that folder. ]

Comment: I tried to reinstall after deleting all related folders still not able to install. Installation window stops at "Setting up the package cache..."